# Pretty-print Lua source-code in external file, without embedding it in the HTML file

Tags: html, lua, syntax-highlighting, pretty-print

Since my experience with HTML is fairly rudimentary (and pretty old), I am not sure if my requirement is realistic.

Lets say that I have quite a few files containing Lua source-code, and all of them have the ".lua" extension and available in a particular subdirectory. What I'd like to do is create a static index.html file, which when loaded in a browser, would show the list of the lua source-code files in a drop-down. Once one of the source-code files is selected, I'd like that the file gets loaded into an "area" on the same page, and is pretty-printed, i.e. with syntax-highlighting in browser. I was wondering if I could use something like the [google-code-prettyfy](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) for the syntax-highlighting part ? Also, I am not clear if an external lua sourcecode file can be loaded, and displayed within a certain region of html page as being rendered. If yes, would appreciate elaboration on the how part.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lua, unless by "loading a Lua file" you mean "executing a Lua file" in the same way an embedded Javascript script gets executed in an HTML page. Lua sources are just text files, as far as rendering them in a web page is concerned.

Comment: "loading a Lua file" was more in the sense of "including" Lua source code, for beautification and display of the code, not executing the Lua source code. Treating them as text files is good enough, just that I want to "include" then and beautify them, at runtime.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati, Personally I don't think that discussion of how to document and present Lua source code is completely off topic. Lua presents its own challenges for code coloring.

Comment: @RBerteig Ok, fair point. From the OP wording it seemed to me the problem was about the interaction between the web page and the prettyfier program and that Lua was just an example (so the Lua tag could have been misleading). Indeed, What you say makes sense, so I retire my objection to tagging the question also as Lua.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [LDoc](https://github.com/stevedonovan/LDoc) can be used to accomplish a lot of what you want, much as [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) would be used for a C language source kit.

Both are heavily driven by inclusion of specially formatted comments that carry documentation.

I know Doxygen can fold source code into the generated document set, I don't recall about LDoc. Both are actively under development.

It isn't necessarily a bad idea to use both tools on a project, especially if you have C source code implementing Lua modules. You could use Doxygen to build the overall document tree for your engine and C modules, and LDoc to build documentation of the Lua parts. It should be possible with a little care and configuration of both tools to get them to play well together.

Comment: Thanks @RBerteig. I want to be able to able to do syntax-highlighting of any Lua code, such as, as soon as it is uploaded to a website. I believe LDoc and LuaDoc require some annotation / commenting of source code, no ? I will check out LDoc (and also LuaDoc) to see if they can be used to generate any useful HTML files, containing pretty-printed code (syntax-highlighting, line numbers etc.) if they have no comments. However, it still requires this offline (batch conversion) phase.